# Custom BCS indexing connector and changelog inremental crawl: ChangedIdEnumerator method is not working

Tags: custom, bcs, crawling, changelog

I am writing a custom indexing connector using changelog incremental crawl approach.

The full crawl is working perfectly. All atems are indexed and queryable.

The problem is that incremental crawl is not working: crawler starts full crawl and ChangedIdEnumerator and DeletedIdEnumerator methods are not called.

I have tried the Timestamp-Based Incremental Crawl with my connector and it works perfect.
But we need changelog incremental crawl because where are millions of items in the external system and they are changing.

I have tried changelog crawl with .NET connector and it works wonderful.
It is described very good in article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg512147.aspx but only for for .NET connectors .

But we need custom connector because our external system doesn't have static interfaces.

............
I will try to describe my connector.

1. Modell has next stereotypes: SpecificFinder, Finder, ChangedIdEnumerator, DeletedIdEneumerator, StreamAccessor
   ...


     
       ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.ConnectorLobUri, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9
       ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.ConnectorNamingContainer, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9
       ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.BdcConnector, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9
     
     
     
       
     
     
       
         
           Name

   ```
       <!--        SpecificFinder          -->
       <Method Name="ReadItem" IsStatic="false">
         <Parameters>
           <Parameter Direction="In" Name="id">
             <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" Name="ID" />
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="returnParameter">
             <TypeDescriptor TypeName="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.Product, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9" Name="Product">
               <TypeDescriptors>
                 <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" Name="ID" />
                 <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Manufacturer" />
                 <TypeDescriptor Name="Name" TypeName="System.String" />
               </TypeDescriptors>
             </TypeDescriptor>
           </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
         <MethodInstances>
           <MethodInstance Type="SpecificFinder" ReturnParameterName="returnParameter" Default="true" Name="ReadItem" DefaultDisplayName="Read Product">
           </MethodInstance>
         </MethodInstances>
       </Method>

       <!--        AssociationNavigator          -->          
       <Method Name="GetProductsList" LobName="GetProductsList" IsStatic="false">
         <Parameters>
           <Parameter Name="productsList" Direction="In">
             <TypeDescriptor Name="productsList" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierEntityNamespace="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom" IdentifierEntityName="Product" IdentifierName="ID" ForeignIdentifierAssociationName="GetProductsListInstance" ForeignIdentifierAssociationEntityName="Product" ForeignIdentifierAssociationEntityNamespace="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom"/>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter Name="Return" Direction="Return">
             <TypeDescriptor Name="Return" TypeName="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.Product[], ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9" IsCollection="true">
               <TypeDescriptors>
                 <TypeDescriptor Name="Item" TypeName="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.Product, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9">
                   <TypeDescriptors>
                     <TypeDescriptor Name="ID" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierEntityNamespace="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom" IdentifierEntityName="Product" IdentifierName="ID" />
                   </TypeDescriptors>
                 </TypeDescriptor>
               </TypeDescriptors>
             </TypeDescriptor>
           </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
         <MethodInstances>
           <Association Name="GetProductsListInstance" Type="AssociationNavigator" ReturnParameterName="Return" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="Return">
             <Properties>
               <Property Name="DirectoryLink" Type="System.String">x</Property>
             </Properties>
             <SourceEntity Name="Product" Namespace="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom" />
             <DestinationEntity Name="Product" Namespace="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom" />
           </Association>
         </MethodInstances>
       </Method>           

       <!--        Finder          -->
       <Method Name="ReadList" IsStatic="false">
         <Parameters>
           <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="returnParameter">
             <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.Product, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9]]" IsCollection="true" Name="ProductList">
               <TypeDescriptors>
                 <TypeDescriptor Name="Product" TypeName="ProductConnectorCustom.ProductModelCustom.Product, ProductConnectorCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a8b3943b0419acb9">
                   <TypeDescriptors>
                     <TypeDescriptor Name="ID" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" />
                     <TypeDescriptor Name="Manufacturer" TypeName="System.String" />
                     <TypeDescriptor Name="Name" TypeName="System.String" />
                   </TypeDescriptors>
                 </TypeDescriptor>
               </TypeDescriptors>
             </TypeDescriptor>
           </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
         <MethodInstances>
             <MethodInstance Type="Finder" ReturnParameterName="returnParameter" Default="true" Name="ReadList" DefaultDisplayName="Product List"></MethodInstance>
         </MethodInstances>
       </Method>

       <!--        ChangedIdEnumerator          -->
       <Method Name="ReadChangedIds" IsStatic="false">
         <Properties>
           <Property Name="LastRunDate" Type="System.DateTime">2013-01-01 00:00:00Z</Property>
         </Properties>
         <FilterDescriptors>
           <FilterDescriptor Name="LastRunDate" Type="InputOutput">
             <Properties>
               <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String">ChangedItemCookie</Property>
             </Properties>
           </FilterDescriptor>
           <FilterDescriptor Name="Timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
         </FilterDescriptors>
         <Parameters>
           <Parameter Name="LastRunDate" Direction="InOut">
             <TypeDescriptor Name="LastRunDateTypeDescriptor" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastRunDate">
               <Interpretation>
                 <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
               </Interpretation>
             </TypeDescriptor>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter Name="returnIds" Direction="Return">
             <TypeDescriptor Name="DeletedIds" TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]" IsCollection="true">
               <TypeDescriptors>
                 <TypeDescriptor Name="ID" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="ID" />
               </TypeDescriptors>
             </TypeDescriptor>
           </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
         <MethodInstances>
           <MethodInstance Name="ReadChangedIds" Type="ChangedIdEnumerator" Default="true" ReturnParameterName="returnIds"></MethodInstance>
         </MethodInstances>
       </Method>
   ```
2. Code

Implemented are the SystemUtility based on StructuredRepositorySystemUtility, 
NamingContainer implements INamingContainer, CustomLobUri class derives from LobUri.

............

I have tried all things but it doesn't work!

Have somebody ever tried to write something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I also used changelog incremental crawl approach and it worked for me.

Here's an example:

```
<Method Name="ReadIncrementalList" IsStatic="false">
                        <FilterDescriptors>
                            <FilterDescriptor Name="LastCrawl" Type="InputOutput">
                                <Properties>
                                    <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String">ChangedItemCookie</Property>
                                </Properties>
                            </FilterDescriptor>
                            <FilterDescriptor Name="timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
                        </FilterDescriptors>
                        <Parameters>
                            <Parameter Name="lastCrawlDate" Direction="InOut">
                                <TypeDescriptor Name="LastCrawlDate" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastCrawl">
                                    <Interpretation>
                                        <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
                                    </Interpretation>
                                </TypeDescriptor>
                            </Parameter>
                            <Parameter Name="returnIds" Direction="Return">
                                <TypeDescriptor Name="returnIds" TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]" IsCollection="true">
                                    <TypeDescriptors>
                                        <TypeDescriptor Name="id" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="IncId" />
                                    </TypeDescriptors>
                                </TypeDescriptor>
                            </Parameter>
                        </Parameters>
                        <MethodInstances>
                            <MethodInstance Name="ReadIncrementalListInstance" Type="ChangedIdEnumerator" ReturnParameterName="returnIds">

                            </MethodInstance>
                        </MethodInstances>
                    </Method>
                    <Method Name="GetDeletedIds" IsStatic="false">
                        <FilterDescriptors>
                            <FilterDescriptor Name="LastCrawl" Type="InputOutput">
                                <Properties>
                                    <Property Name="SynchronizationCookie" Type="System.String">DeletedItemCookie</Property>
                                </Properties>
                            </FilterDescriptor>
                            <FilterDescriptor Name="timestamp" Type="Timestamp" />
                        </FilterDescriptors>
                        <Parameters>
                            <Parameter Name="lastCrawlDate" Direction="InOut">
                                <TypeDescriptor Name="LastCrawlDate" TypeName="System.DateTime" IsCollection="false" AssociatedFilter="LastCrawl">
                                    <Interpretation>
                                        <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
                                    </Interpretation>
                                </TypeDescriptor>
                            </Parameter>
                            <Parameter Name="DeletedIds" Direction="Return">
                                <TypeDescriptor Name="DeletedIds" TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]" IsCollection="true">
                                    <TypeDescriptors>
                                        <TypeDescriptor Name="Identifier1" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="IncId" />
                                    </TypeDescriptors>
                                </TypeDescriptor>
                            </Parameter>
                        </Parameters>
                        <MethodInstances>
                            <MethodInstance Name="GetDeletedIdsInstance" Type="DeletedIdEnumerator" ReturnParameterName="DeletedIds">

                            </MethodInstance>
                        </MethodInstances>
                    </Method>
```

Comment: Hi Alex! Thank you for your answer. Do you use custom and not .Net connector? I have compared yours and mine models and I can't found differences.

Comment: If crawl starts, it calls first SpecificFinder. I have defined AssociationNavigator to forward this call to Finder. Do you use something like this? May be problem is here? 

Thank you, Dmitry

Comment: Although the article doesn't have your specific scenario, it explains step by step how to achieve parent/child relationship using Visual Studio BCS solution:

http://blog.johnnyt.me/2013/03/crawling-with-fast-and-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

I have fond solution for the problem:

The identity parameter should not be set in the Initialize method in the class derived from LobUri. I'm getting ChangedIdEnumerator and DeletedIdEnumerator called now.

Comment: Could you provide some code snippets about the changes you did to the initialize method? I'm having similar issue incremental crawl runs full crawl

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem (at least for SharePoint 2013, is that after the IdEnumerator, ChangedIdEnumerator and DeletedIdEnumerator, the Specific finder is never invoked.